# How to call default node validation functions

Tags: nodes, forms

I have a custom node-creation form for which I have my own validation function. How can I make sure that after my validation function the form goes through the same validation that it would have done on the original node-creation form?
Some thing like [`node_validate`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_validate/6) looks like the kind of thing I need, but it works on `$node` objects rather than forms.
The order of operations I perceive to be the best is

1. On submit run custom validation
2. If custom validation passes run the normal node validation
3. If node validation succeeds insert values in the database

Is that a good and Drupal way?

Comment: Apparently `node_validate()` is useless on a custom form because the errors get displayed but aren't acted on.  There doesn't seem to be a way to catch the errors, even with `form_get_errors()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your form has a structure similar to the one used for the node edit form, then you can use `node_validate()`, which is called from the form validation handler for the node edit form.

```
function node_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  node_validate($form_state['values'], $form);
}
```

`node_validate()` converts the first argument in an object using the following code.

```
  // Convert the node to an object, if necessary.
  $node = (object) $node;
  $type = node_get_types('type', $node);
```

Your form validation handler's code should be similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  // Run your validation code.
  node_validate($form_state['values'], $form);
}
```

As general rule, the validation code should go in the form validation handler. If the form validation handler set any error, the form submission handler is not called, and the user is returned to the form to correct what is wrong in the data that has been submitted.

Comment: I was surprised that I could pass `$form` to `node_validate()` when it's expecting a `$node`.

Comment: `$form` is necessary for `node_validate()`, as it is the parameter required from `hook_validate()`, and `hook_nodeapi('validate')` (`hook_node_validate()` in Drupal 7), which are invoked by `node_validate()`.

Comment: CAN YOU say how to do it in drupal 7

Answer (score 1):

[`node_validate()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_validate/7) will solve the problem.  The original validation process will not be affected.